# Int to byte array of binary representation in java

Tags: java, arrays, binary, int, byte

I'm in the process of implementing the SHA-256 algo in Java, and im at the padding step where I need to append the binary representation of the messages' length as 8 bytes.

So say the messages' length was 16bits, I would have to pad with 0x000000000000000F, and i'd like to have this into a byte array.
I suppose I can convert the int into a string representing the hex/binary value, and then tokenize the string and then parse the tokens into a byte array, however this sounds very overcomplicated, So i'm wondering if there's a "simpler" more effective way to accomplish this?

To simplify it, turn an integer k into a byte array containing the 64 bit binary representation of k.

Comment: Why not just set bytes in the byte array to 0?  Though byte array elements already default to zero anyway.

Comment: I don't want to pad with only 0's i want to pad with the 64bit binary representation of some integer k

Comment: Use `ByteBuffer` (which would be a good idea anyway) and you can use `putInt`.